# Remove query string parameter to create a more user-friendly URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

I have this `.htaccess` file and I have no knowledge with mod_rewrite,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php  [L]
```

What I want to achieve is to have `localhost/viewticket/${id}` instead of `localhost/viewticket.php?id=123`

I have tried many `.htaccess` rules but none worked except this one that hides `.php` in my URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this one for you, just erase yours and copy this one enjoy^^

````
IndexIgnore */*

Options FollowSymLinks
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^viewticket/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ viewticket.php?id=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php  [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>```
````

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've changed your internal URLs so you are linking to `/viewticket/<id>`. Then add the following at the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
# Prevent MutliViews rewriting "viewticket" and omitting the URL parameter
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect any direct requests to "/viewticket.php?id=<id>" to "/viewticket/<id>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d*)
RewriteRule ^(viewticket)\.php$ /$1/%1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite "/viewticket/<id>" to "viewticket.php?id=<id>"
RewriteRule ^(viewticket)/(\d*)$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

If you are not expecting any query string on your "pretty" `/viewticket/<id>` URL then remove the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag in the last rule.

`$1` is a backreference to the first capturing group (parenthesised subpattern) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Likewise, `%1` is a backreference to the first capturing group in the last matched *CondPattern* (`RewriteCond` directive).

Always test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you are sure everything is working as intended. Clear your browser cache before testing.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

---

***Additional:***

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php  [L]
> ```

Your existing directives (that remove the trailing slash and `.php` extension) are not quite correct.

Your first rule that *unconditionally* removes the trailing slash will also "try" to remove the trailing slash from directories as well - which will conflict with mod_dir and result in a redirect loop. The negated character class `[^/]` (to match a non-slash character) in the middle of the regex would seem to be superfluous. This also redirects to HTTP (not HTTPS)?

The second rule that *removes* the `.php` extension would also erroneosuly match `.php` should it appear in the query string portion of the URL. eg. `/foo?bar.php` would be redirected to `/foo?bar`. Although the regex `([^.]+)` does avoid the perhaps more common case of `/foo.php?bar.php` being erroneously redirected.

The third rule that appends the `.php` extension via an internal rewrite could potentially result in a rewrite-loop (500 Internal Server Error) if you received a request of the form `/foo/bar` and `/foo.php` exists in the root of the filesystem. Also, the (optional) trailing slash is also captured by the capturing subgroup, since the `*` quantifier is greedy. This would also result in a malformed rewrite, if it wasn't for the first rule that removes the trailing slash. (But since the trailing slash is removed then the *optional* trailing slash in this rule is redundant.)

If you still need these rules to remove the trailing slash and handle extensionless `.php` URLs then have these rules as follows. Make sure you are already linking to the extensionless URLs internally. These rules should *follow* the rule block I posted above.

```
# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove ".php" extension if present on the initial request
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Append ".php" extension if request maps to a PHP file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php  [L]
```

These directives (and your original directives for that matter) do assume the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L
```

And if it won't works you can read this PDF file: [How to remove PHP or HTML extensions with htaccess](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ic0my9c3jvjfp21/How%20to%20remove%20PHP%20or%20HTML%20extensions%20with%20htaccess.pdf?dl=0)